# Inform the user what page of the pager it is -- on top of the page as well

Tags: views, 10

When we create a View of pages we can give it a pager. That pager typically appears **underneath** the view. This can cause an accessibility problem of a user mistakenly clicking to go to a next page without understanding what the current page is, especially if the page is very long and the the fold of the new page doesn't indicate what is the current page on the pager series.

The pager is rendered as in the following screenshots.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

How can I show the user the current page **above** the view as well?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The pager shown in a view already shows the current page, even when the mini pager is used. For example, with Drupal 10 and its default theme, it appears like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KX2q.png). Probably, the used theme is not showing correctly the pager.

Comment: @apaderno my theme is olivero and the pager is shown fine underneath the main content but I want to somehow show the current page above the main content as well, perhaps even duplicating the pager to the top part of the page. I can duplicate it with JavaScript in a `cloneNode(true);` but I doubt it's a good way to go.

Comment: Go for JavaScript. Because whatever top of the page means and depending of how the view is built, it can become quite difficult to retrieve the pager states outside of the context of the view.

Comment: My comment was for *This can cause an accessibility problem of a user mistakenly clicking to go to a next page **without understanding what the current page is**.* The current page is shown near the link to go to the next page. If users do not notice that, they would not notice that if the page number is placed on the top of the page. I could understand if the problem is that users do not understand what those numbers are, but in that case it should be sufficient to change how the pager is rendered to add more explicit labels, for example *Current page:* near the current page number.

Comment: @leymannx I guess the main problem is not where the pager is shown, but for the users to understand that the numbers shown on the pager are page numbers, and the highlighted one is the current page.

Comment: May you add a screenshot that shows the pager in that view? This would allow to give a more helpful answer.

Comment: @apaderno it's a standard all-regular full pager of 5 items per page (in a simple blog View). I think I'll just clone it with JavaScript perhaps, or clone the `pager__item pager__item--active pager__item--number` with JavaScript and add some text near it like "You are here in this page `PAGE_NUMBER`".

Comment: Even if it is standard, the theme could change how the pager is rendered. For example, with the Seven theme, it would be rendered like *‹‹ Page 2 Next page ››*, while the Claro theme would not show *Page* near the page number. Modules can alter how a pager is rendered. That is why I asked for a screenshot.

Comment: @apaderno I have added two screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template_preprocess_views_view() hook to get current page number

```
function Mymodule_preprocess_views_view(&$vars){
  $view = $vars['view'];
  $id = $view->storage->id();
  if($id == 'view_name'){
   $pager_number = $view->pager->current_page;
   // current page key value start from 0 so add by 1
   // set current_page variable that can access in view twig
   $vars['current_page'] = $pager_number + 1;
  }
}
```

**Note:** Now you can use the "current_page" in views-view.html.twig by rendering like this:
{{ current_page }}
Make sure override view twig by view name displayed by theme suggestion

**To override view twig can follow naming convention like this:**
views-view--machine_name.html.twig

Answer (score 0):

In the View add a Header: Global: Text area and fill in the text:

```
[view:current-page]
```

There is a list with more pager variables in the section *Available global token replacements*.